# Erro com aplicação de CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou ultilizando a o Adobe Brackets pela primeira vez, e estou aplicando um estilo em CSS em um Pequeno "Projeto" em Html , mas infelizmente não esta gerando resultados, relacionados ao CSS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu nunca usei Adobe Brackets mas você não tem que pôr a referência do ficheiro css no `<header>` do seu `index.html`?

Comment: Ja fiz isso a referencia na linha onde tem o "Link" . consegui resolver o erro, mesmo assim obrigado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua segunda imagem, que seria o arquivo **main.css** tem uma `tag` que não existe:

`<stily></stily>`

Retire ela do código.

Além disso, quando o arquivo é `.css` você não precisa colocar essa `tag`, que a correta seria `<style>`.

Outra coisa, você está aplicando um `CSS` num `h3`, mas no HTML não tem nenhum `h3`, e sim um `h1`.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado! deu certo :)
ah , tem como explicar essa parte !
Além disso, quando o arquivo é .css você não precisa colocar essa tag, que a correta seria <style> .
Não entendi ela muito bem.

Comment: Quando o arquivo é `CSS` não precisa colocar essa tag `<style>`, porquê você já está dizendo que o arquivo é um `.css`. A tag `<stily>` não existe. O que é existe é `<style>`.